# system don't save .bash_profile and source it at startup zch

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, zshrc

since last MacOS terminal used zsh then i face
every time i open terminal and use some thing like flutter

error

```
michaelatef@michaels-iMac ~ % flutter                   
zsh: command not found: flutter
```

and have every time to run

```
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

manually to work with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.bash_profile` is an init file for Bash only. Why zsh uses bash's config file?

```sh
cp "$HOME/.bash_profile" "$HOME/.zshrc"
```

Init files for ZSH:

1. `/etc/zshenv`
2. `~/.zshenv`
3. login mode:

   1. `/etc/zprofile`
   2. `~/.zprofile`
4. interactive:

   1. `/etc/zshrc`
   2. `~/.zshrc`
5. login mode:

   1. `/etc/zlogin`
   2. `~/.zlogin`

Init files for Bash,

1. login mode:

   1. `/etc/profile`
   2. `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile` (only first one that exists)
2. interactive non-login:

   1. `/etc/bash.bashrc` (some Linux; not on Mac OS X)
   2. `~/.bashrc`
3. non-interactive:

   1. source file in `$BASH_ENV`

References

- [Unix Shell Initialization](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Unix-shell-initialization)